# How do you actually find what you want from offline QT documentation?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qml

I wanted to go through QtQuick/QML Button API, which I found [**here**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html) online.
But I can't find it from the offline documentation available in QTCreator. The offline search gives me less relevant results.
Any tips for searching...?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One trick I use is this:

1. Type the item (e.g. "Button") into the code editor
2. Hover my mouse cursor over the item
3. Press F1

That will open the documentation for the Button QML type. Works in C++ too.

Answer (score 1):

Google has much more powerful search engine comparing to offline documentation browser. So you just didn't find matching article in help browser search. You can:

- Find "Button" instead of "button" in help browser search results
- Place cursor on interesting identifier in code and press F1 to show help
- Select appropriate documentation in "Contents" mode of help browser left panel

Comment: Agreed, Google is very powerful. There's a Chrome extension called "Qt Doc Search" that helps users narrow down *online* searches using Google: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/qt-doc-search/gfigdpnkjnilcielpnmfmdnnbloabjoh